# arduino thread update volatile variable

Tags: multithreading, arduino, volatile

I want to use multithread programming with Arduino.

I wrote some code ato update the variable `tempsPose` but it doesn't work (the led blinks always at the same speed).

How can I change the following code in order to update `tempsPose` variable in the function `blinkled13` when this variable is mofified in the loop function?

```
#include <Thread.h>
Thread myThread = Thread();

int ledPin = 13;
volatile int tempsPose ;

void blinkLed13()
{
  \\i would like the value of 'tempspose' to be updated
  \\ when the value of the variable changes in the blinkLed13 function
  while(1){
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(tempsPose);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(tempsPose);
  }
}


void setup() {
  tempsPose = 100;
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myThread.onRun(blinkLed13);
  if(myThread.shouldRun())
    myThread.run();
}

void loop() {
  for(int j=0; j<100; j++){
    delay(200);
    \\some code which change the value of 'tempsPose' 
    \\this code is pseudo code
    tempsPose = tempsPose + 1000;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples are all "one-shot" (no infinite loops) and the code `if (thread.shouldRun()) thread.run();` is inside of `loop()`. So I suppose it won't get into the `loop()` at all in your case.

For example more interactive code ('+' adds 100ms, '-' substracts 100ms):

```
#include <Thread.h>

Thread myThread = Thread();
int ledPin = 13;
volatile int tempsPose;

void blinkLed13() {
  // i would like the value of 'tempspose' to be updated
  // when the value of the variable changes in the blinkLed13 function
  static bool state = 0;

  state = !state;
  digitalWrite(ledPin, state);

  Serial.println(state ? "On" : "Off");
}

void setup() {
  tempsPose = 100;
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myThread.onRun(blinkLed13);
  myThread.setInterval(tempsPose);
}

void loop() {
  if(myThread.shouldRun()) myThread.run();

  if (Serial.available()) {
    uint8_t ch = Serial.read(); // read character from serial
    if (ch == '+' && tempsPose < 10000) { // no more than 10s
      tempsPose += 100;
      myThread.setInterval(tempsPose);
    } else if (ch == '-' && tempsPose > 100) { // less than 100ms is not allowed here
      tempsPose -= 100;
      myThread.setInterval(tempsPose);
    }
    Serial.println(tempsPose);
  }
}
```

Comment: With the above code, the Led 13 doesn't stop blinkink (while(1) in the function) but the delay does not change with time

Comment: That is because it never left  `blinkLed13`. It never get into the `loop` to change that delay. Just print these changed values into the Serial. There will be nothing, because it's stucked in the `setup` function and `myThread.run()`

Comment: Thank for your comment but I don't really understand what you wrote. Can you please show me some code.

Comment: @user3052784 Small example that will react for + or - sent over Serial in serial monitor.

Comment: Ok I see how I have to do now. Thank you very much :)